# how to detect specific part of the URL and modify it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing website using asp.net. In there I mainly use URL to pass parameters.

I have URL structure like this

```
http://localhost:51247/yyy/zzz/hrforum/(if its in my local PC)
http://test.com/yyy/zzz/hrforum/
```

I need to detect that zzz part and replace it with another word. I tried many things including Regex patterns but seems I am doing git wrong way. Please help me to detect it. Modify it and rebuild the URL

Codes I tried

```
 Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"/([\w\s]+?\;){2}/");
    var match = myRegex.Match(fullUrl);
    var firstName = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? Is this for routing or something else?

Comment: Please note, the word "code" is used as a "*mass noun*" meaning it doesn't need an "s" or a "z"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method of doing this would be to use the [Uri.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=net-5.0) property.  For example:

```
    Uri uriAddress1 = new Uri("http://test.com/yyy/zzz/hrforum/");
    Uri uriAddress2 = new Uri("ttp://localhost:51247/yyy/zzz/hrforum/");
    
    Console.WriteLine(uriAddress1.Segments[2] == uriAddress2.Segments[2]);
    Console.WriteLine("Segment 2 of Address 1: {0} Segment 2 of Address 2: {1}", uriAddress1.Segments[2].Trim('/'),uriAddress2.Segments[2].Trim('/'));
```

Output:

> True
>
> Segment 2 of Address 1: zzz Segment 2 of Address 2: zzz

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but to answer this question:

> How to detect specific part of the URL and modify it?

I think you can use [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class instead of using Regex.

```cs
var uri = new Uri("http://test.com/yyy/zzz/hrforum/");
var pathName = uri.PathAndQuery;

foreach (var item in pathName.Split('/'))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

// output:
// yyy
// zzz
// hrforum
```